# Como inserir um asterisco a cada 3 caracteres?

Tags: c

Como faço para digitar um valor qualquer, seja texto ou número, e a cada 3 posições ser inserido um asterisco?

Exemplo: digito `123456789`, ao apertar enter aparece: `123*456*789*`

Comment: Olá. O que é que já tentou fazer? Dizer-lhe como fazer não me parece solução e pela pergunta soa a trabalho de casa. Mostre-nos o que tentou ou o que tem, mas não peça para fazermos o código por si.

Answer (score 2):

A lógica para o que quer fazer pode ser escrita assim:

1. Aloque um buffer com 134% do tamanho original para poder acomodar a string com asteriscos.
2. Inicialize uma variável `i` com valor zero.
3. Itere sobre a string original com a variável `j` variando de zero até `strlen(str)`.

   1. Copie um caractere da string em `j` para o buffer em `i` e incremente `i`:

      ```
      buffer[i] = str[j];
      ++i;
      ```
   2. Se `i` é múltiplo  de `4` (`i % 4 == 0`) copie um asterisco para o buffer e incremente:

      ```
      buffer[i] = '*';
      ++i;
      ```
4. Finalize o buffer com um terminador nulo (`buffer[i] = '\0'`) e não esqueça de liberar a memória quando acabar de usar.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a resposta está em sua própria pergunta:

1 - a pessoa tem um lugar onde digitar uma entrada

2 - quando ela presisona enter, este valor é processado:

2.1 - ele pega tudo o que você digitou;

2.2 - copia 3 caracteres, insere um *, copia os próximos 3 caracteres...

3 - no final pega esta cópia com os * inseridos e exibe para o usuário.